# accessing additional jboss log file

Tags: java, logging, jboss

I've added another log file and I was wondering how I access it from within Java code. I can't find anything on it.

I want a separate log file for user actions.

Here is my standalone.xml, for JBOSS AS 7.1.1.

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <size-rotating-file-handler name="USER" autoflush="false">
            <level name="ALL"/>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="user.log"/>
            <rotate-size value="50m"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </size-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="user" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="ALL"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="USER"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
    </subsystem>
```

I'm trying to write to it like so:

```
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("USER");
logger.info("user did something");
```

It creates the user.log on startup but still writes to server.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your categories don't match. In the configuration you define the logger category as `user` (lowercase). In your code example you define the category as `USER` (uppercase). Change the categories to match and it will work.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
    ...
    <size-rotating-file-handler name="USER" autoflush="false">
        <level name="ALL"/>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="user.log"/>
        <rotate-size value="50m"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </size-rotating-file-handler>
    <logger category="USER" use-parent-handlers="false">
        <level name="ALL"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="USER"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    ...
</subsystem>
```

Comment: also, it wouldn't work until I added the formatter/pattern-formatter section to size-rotating-file-handler.

Comment: That's interesting. It should have a default format if one isn't specified.